# Dicom viewer in my php web application

Tags: php, dicom

I am doing one web application for my client. We have one issue. Right now we have dicom image viewer of nagoya tech dicom viewer. We have integrated that viewer in our PHP web application.

When we upload that file. File uploads successfully but we not able to see anything screen seems blank.

I don't know what specification is missing with my application. I am not able to see this .DCM image in my dicom viewer.

I am searching this for long time what is the issue but I am not able to do this.

Please help me to load image in this with all things.

Here is the image.

[image]

Comment: Since the patient info is also not displayed, either the upload is actually failing, the data file is the wrong type or you are not parsing the file properly. It is not solely an image display error.

Comment: Hy  john, we are able to see the viewer but we are not able to see the uploaded file we have try to upload lots of different type of file but still we not able to check any of the file. I don't know why we not able to see any of the uploaded file. We have also check all the thing which is needed to setup this kind of issue but since that is not able help us we have come here.  I don't  know what we are missing in this. Is there any specif configuration that is need OR something I don't know ?

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be two variables here to me:

1. Does the viewer work at all?
2. Is the upload successfully transferring the file?

The best way to troubleshoot this would be to put a file on the server to test with the PHP viewer IMO. If this image is viewed successfully, we can rule out a problem with the viewer itself. At this point, try uploading that same known good file through the client to then be displayed. If this fails, compare the uploaded file with the known good file for differences. If the file is 0 KB, then the uploading has failed.

If you cannot find any good file to test with, then you should verify the parsing of the file to figure out why that is failing.